# Can't get Modal to work with carousel-video sourced

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

So I have this carousel from http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. I decided with my carousel that once you click the image-a video appears. Well I want this video to load into a Modal Image-with a closeout function. The first line of code for div id....is the image onced clicked the video appears. The rest below it I'll just copy and paste the first part. (Repeat of the same image/video four times-until I decide to switch things out)

```
 <section class="center slider">
 <div id="video" style="display:none;"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/36_e3qbYhEs" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
  <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('video').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('videopic').style.display = 'none'; void(0);">
  <img id="videopic" src="images/350x300.png" alt="Video Picture" /></a>



<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
</div>
</section>
```

I have the JS and CSS all working fine I just can't implant a function where you click the image the "image(video)" will open in a new window. Sorry about my wording. I am beginner and learning as I go. I know what I want it to do but can't figure out how.

Please let me know if I need to provide anything further.

Comment: You want to click the Video Pic, and it opens the YouTube iframe in another window?

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you're looking for that might help you in Googling would be that you want your video to open in a *lightbox*.

Answering specifically how to do this in your particular circumstance is too broad for this site, even if you give us more code to look at. But generally the way you can accomplish this is to use JavaScript to toggle a class on one or more elements when your slideshow images are clicked, and adding that class would trigger the video to show up, while clicking the exit button would remove the class so things go back to their original appearance.

Here is a really basic example, but you can basically take this concept and make it as simple or complicated as you want. You could, for example, toggle a class on the `html` or `body` tag of your page and then adjust the CSS of a bunch of stuff on the page based on whether that class is applied.

If you're using jQuery, there are plugins designed exactly for this purpose that will automatically give you a ton of settings to do things like automatically size and perfectly center your lightbox in the viewport and take care of mobile functionality and whatnot. [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) and [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) are a couple examples.

```js
var lightboxImg = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

lightboxImg.addEventListener('click', function(){
 this.parentNode.classList.toggle('lightbox');
});
document.getElementById('exit').addEventListener('click', function(){
 lightboxImg.parentNode.classList.toggle('lightbox');
});
```

```css
/* relevant stuff */
#iframe {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: -100px;
 left: -100px;
}
#exit {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: -290px;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: white;
}
section div.lightbox #iframe {
 display: block;
}
img:hover, #exit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* just for display purposes */
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
section {
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: gold;
 position: relative;
 left: calc(50% - 200px);
 top: calc(50% - 150px);
}
section div {
 position: relative;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section class="center slider">
 <div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200?text=click%20me">
  <div id="iframe"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400?text=your%20iframe"><span id="exit">X</span></div>
 </div>
</section>
```